# While installing Debian KDE on i386 computer, Locks me out unexpectedly

Tags: debian, software-installation, kde

I have a Toshiba Satellite M105 currently installing Debian KDE 11 and after around 5 mins, locks me out unexpectedly and the password to get back in is unknown. Help?

I have not touched any settings whatsoever since the software is currently installing.

Comment: laptop with 1 GB RAM? and you are trying to install Debian 11 with KDE?

Comment: Idk how many Gs of ram i have in my computer exactly all i know is that i have more than 2 Gs since thats how much ram i have in the only ram module that the computer has, so there has to be some built-in ram of unknown value

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `passwd` command before beginning the install to set a password, so that when you get locked out you can log back in. Most live and install disks dont have passwords set for any of the users, they just command the DM to automatically log in.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate at what step the OP should use the `passwd` command when installing the system, and how to access a console such that this change will have an effect on the running installer system.

Comment: I somehow managed to finish the installation without having to log back in idk how i did it but however it was it was successful and works just fine